# Gradle not compiling dependency jars in lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar, build.gradle

I am new to gradle and learning now. I am trying to build a runnable jar using gradle(My builded jar should be run from command prompt). I just started with a simple `HelloWorld` project with a dependency and try to build it using gradle. I am not using maven. So I added the dependency jar to the lib folder inside project folder. Below are the details.

Gradle Version: 3.1
Eclipse Version: Neon

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.padhu.test;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LocalTime currentTime = new LocalTime();
        System.out.println("The current local time is: " + currentTime);

        System.out.println("Hello World");

    }

}
```

**Project structure:**

[project_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TCDJ.jpg)

**build_path_snap**

[build_path_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N2qs.jpg)

**build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.padhu.test.HelloWorld'

repositories {

   flatDir {
      dirs 'lib'
   }
}

dependencies {


    compile files(fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar']))

    }

jar {
  manifest {
    attributes(

      'Main-Class': 'com.padhu.test.HelloWorld'
    )
  }
}
```

I can successfully execute `gradle build` in my cmd and jar file is getting generated.  But inside jar file, I can see only HelloWorld folder structure, but couldnt see the dependency files. So I am not able to run the jar from command prompt since I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/LocalTime`..

I tried fixing the issue myself by searching and reading blogs..but I am not able to run the jar successfully.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you misunderstand, how does `application` plugin behave. It doesn't make a so-called fat-jar, which includes all it's dependencies, rather creates a jar and able to run it, adding all the dependencies to the classpath.

You can run your application as follows:

```
gradle run
```

Or you can use the automatically applied distribution plugin and create a distribution of your project with scripts to start it and all the dependent libraries in separate folder. Just run it as:

```
gradle distZip
```

You can read more about it in the [official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).

Comment: In my case I added the dependencies that I need from maven repository correctly, and it downloads for my local repo and creates a single jar with my app. But I have two custom dependencies that I created, so I put it in a libs folder on root folder project, then added the line: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar').
Added to dependencies in my build.gradle, but it's like gradle dont consider this libs, and the custom dependencies still missing. What do I do?